# Using a vlookup in a Sumifs formula on a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table called Popular_Pages which has columns/metrics Users, Sessions, Page Views etc. I have created a dropdown menu to select which metric to view based on the columns, this dropdown is based on a list in the sheet next to each metric I have the actual call for the table, e.g. Users then [Users]

If I write the formula;

```
=count(popular_pages[Users])
```

I get the correct answer, however, if I write the formula;

```
=count("popular_pages"&VLOOKUP(U13,Settings!$C$65:$E$69,3,FALSE))
```

Where U13 is the dropdown and contains "Users" and the range C65:E69 looks like this, returning [Users]

```
Metric---------|-------Heading-------|--Column Name  
Page Views-----|----------1----------|--[Page Views]  
Users----------|----------2----------|--[Users]  
Sessions-------|----------3----------|--[Sessions]
```

..
..

it does not work I get the standard there is an error in your formula message.

Comment: Hi, yes I think you need to concatenate `[` and `]` like this `=count(popular_pages&"["&VLOOKUP(U13,Settings!$C$65:$E$69,3,FALSE)&"]")`

Comment: @dmb the square brackets are already in the column name

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes `"` on `popular_names` like I wrote on my question? I'm trying like that and get no error

Comment: @dmb Yes still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `VLOOKUP` I used `INDIRECT` instead as follows;

```
=COUNT(INDIRECT("Popular_Pages["&U13&"]"))
```

and I didn't need the the Column Name I could just use what is in U13